# How we use salib sensitivity analysis in model of machine learning (example Random forest)

Tags: python, model, salib

I created a model of prevision machine learning-based (regression problem), and I want to do a sensitivity analysis using the SAlib library.
how to get the sensitivity analysis parameters of my model

`!pip install SAlib`

```
from SALib.sample import latin
from SALib.sample import sobol_sequence
from SALib.sample import morris as morris_samp
from SALib.sample import saltelli
from SALib.analyze import sobol
from SALib.analyze import morris
from SALib.test_functions import Ishigami
from SALib.test_functions import Sobol_G
```

```
problem ={'num_vars': 8,
          'names': ['x1',   'x2',   'x3',   'x4',   'x5',   'x6',   'x7','x8'],
          'bounds': [[1.3,35.25],
                     [28, 111.50],
                     [12, 38.50],
                     [8, 225],
                     [0,6],
                     [1, 7],
                     [0.38, 2.33],
                     [2.5, 89.55]]}
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: There is an implementation of this in ai4water library. Currently only regression problems are supported.
https://ai4water.readthedocs.io/en/dev/model.html#ai4water._main.BaseModel.sensitivity_analysis